# How to determine the number of roots and the dimension of a Lie algebra using Cartan matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra with the Cartan matrix
$$
C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -2\\
-1 & 2
\end{array}\right)
$$

Question:

1. How can the number of roots of $\mathfrak{g}$ be determined from $C$?
2. How can it be shown that the dimension of $\mathfrak{g}$ is 10?

*Note: this is an exam prep question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of roots can be found by using the Cartan matrix to find the type of the root system. In this case the type is $B_2$ (or $C_2$), so there are $8$ roots.

The Lie algebra is the direct sum of a Cartan subalgebra and the weight spaces. In this case the Cartan subalgebra is two dimensional and the 8 weight spaces are one dimensional, so the dimension is 10.