# The root system of $sl(3,\mathbb C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

I want to determine the root-system of the lie algebra $sl(3,\mathbb C)$. Does someone know a good (and complete) reference for this problem?

I know that the root-system is $A_2$ but I want to see a complete proof (calculation) for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compute $DA-AD$ when $A,D\in\mathfrak{sl}_3$ with $D$ diagonal, and deduce the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root system of $A_2$ consists of $\Phi=\{ \pm \alpha,\pm \beta , \pm (\alpha+\beta) \}$, which can be constructed as follows. With the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{R}}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$
and the canonical scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can realize the simple roots as
$$
\alpha=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\beta=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then we obviously have $(\alpha,\alpha)=(\beta,\beta)=1$, and in addition
\begin{align*}
\langle \alpha, \alpha^{\vee}\rangle & = \frac{2(\alpha,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}= 2 ,\\
\langle \alpha, \beta^{\vee}\rangle & =   \frac{2(\alpha,\beta)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}= -1,\\
\langle \beta, \beta^{\vee}\rangle & =2,
\end{align*}
and we obtain the Cartan numbers for type $A_2$. This shows that the root system of $A_2$ consists of $\Phi=\{ \pm \alpha,\pm \beta , \pm (\alpha+\beta) \}$. For additional information also see the MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467330/computing-information-about-a-lie-algebra-from-cartan-matrix), for the case of $B_2$. Of course, the same discussion is valid for type $A_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how I know that this belongs to $sl(3,\mathbb C)$?

Comment: The Cartan numbers characterise the Lie algebra. And $A_2$ is $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: I think your last sentence is the main thing which I dont understand. I thought that $A_2$ is the name of the root system. But you said "$A_2$ is $sl(3,\mathbb C)$", then what is the definition of $A_2$? (Sorry for this "stupid" question.. I am a beginner in this Topic, I hope you can answer this question for me)

Comment: Who downvoted this post ? Incredible !