# Cartan subalgebra of ${\frak so}(5)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I would like to find effectively the Cartan subalgebra of ${\frak so}(5)$. Does anybody knows how to proceed?

**Edit**: I don't want to start from the simple roots and then derive it. I would like to do the pedagogical procedure, starting from the cartan subalgebra and identifying the simple roots.

Comment: thank you for your comment, you're right

Comment: For the simple roots  see also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467330/computing-information-about-a-lie-algebra-from-cartan-matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Cartan subalgebra of $B_2$ (in fact, for all classical simple Lie algebras), see [this handout](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/thomas.leistner/2010-1-honours/LA10-handout03-classical.pdf). Here $B_2$ is the root system of $\mathfrak{so}(5)$.

Comment: do you also have a place where are written some standard procedure to identify the cartan subalgebra?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a linear Lie algebra over an algebraically closed field, then any Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ is the centralizer of a maximal toral Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. There are many standard references, some of them given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_subalgebra).