# Structure constants from Dynkin diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

Is there an easy way to obtain the structure constants of a Lie Algebra starting from its Dynkin diagram?

Comment: Yes, and to add just a little to Dietrich Burde's answer below: this really is quite easy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You can write down the Cartan matrix from the Dynkin diagram as usual, and then proceed with the Serre relations. See also here:

[Computing information about a Lie algebra from cartan matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467330/computing-information-about-a-lie-algebra-from-cartan-matrix)

On the other hand, if you know the name of the root system, then you also know the matrix Lie algebra. In the above case it is $B_2$ and hence the matrix Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(5)$. This gives you the explicit Lie brackets by $[A,B]=AB-BA$.