# How can I see that the Lie algebra $E_8$ has dimension 248

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'd like to see directly from the Cartan Matrix of E8
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right)$$
That is of dimension 248. Clearly I have that the dimension of the Cartan subalgebra is 8 so I cleary have that it is at least of dimension 24 since contains 8 copies of ${e_i,h_i,f_i}$. Is there a way to easily obtain the full dimension of the algebra just from the Cartan Matrix?

Comment: The Cartan decomposition gives $\dim (E_8)=8+|\Phi|$, where $\Phi$ is the root system of $E_8$. This can be computed from the Cartan matrix, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195298/recovering-roots-from-cartan-integers?noredirect=1&lq=1), and we obtain $|\Phi|=240$. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265516/computing-all-the-roots-from-the-cartan-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1), where the roots are constructed from the Cartan matrix in another (easier) example.